# Vue template - render HTML special character codes

Tags: vue.js, special-characters

How can I fully render HTML special characters codes in my Vue template?

For instance I have this JSON data:

```
[{"id":"post91","slug":null,"title":"Breakfast &#038; Tea"}]
```

How can I convert `Breakfast &#038; Tea` to `Breakfast & Tea`?

My Vue template:

```
<h3 class="heading">{{ item.title }}</h3>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The best option is using `v-html` actually:

```
<h3 class="heading" v-html="item.title"></h3>
```

No need of any other libs.

Comment: Yes, you are correct actually. I didn't consider `v-html` but that is a better solution!

Comment: This is the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's easier to use a library like [he](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he) for this:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created(){
    this.message = this.decode('Breakfast &#038; Tea');
  },
  methods:{
    decode(str){
        return he.decode(str);
    }
  },
  data:{
    message: ''
  }
})
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/86k1ge4b/