# Rendering escaped HTML from api call with vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, rendering

I'm trying to render out data returned from an api call with Vue.

One portion of the data is coming in the form of escaped html like so:

```
body: "&lt;ul&gt; ↵ &lt;li&gt;This is &lt;strong&gt;Test 
Text.&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/li&gt; ↵&lt;/ul&gt;"
```

I have tried the v-html directive as follows:

```
      <div  v-for="(item, index) in filteredList"> 
         <div v-html="item.body"></div>
      </div>
```

It's rendering out but but with visible anchor tags, exactly as it looks below, ul, li, strong tags all visible in the browser

```
  <ul> <li>This is &nbsp;<strong>Test Text</strong></li> </ul>
```

I've tried a decoding function (which rendered it exactly the same as the v-html is), a sanitizing plug-in, looked over this post [Vue template - convert HTML special characters (numberic) to symbols?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46874504/vue-template-convert-html-special-characters-numberic-to-symbols) and many others but I just can't seem to get it to render properly

Comment: Vue is protecting you from yourself. Shipping raw HTML over an API like that is bad and you should avoid it. The correct way to do it is send over a JSON object that will allow you to build the object on the client side.

Comment: I added a solution below but agreed with @EmettSpeer that you need to be careful before implementing what HTML is emitted from an API.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

```js
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString("&lt;li&gt;", "text/html");
const textContent = doc.documentElement.textContent;
console.log(textContent);
```

After running it through here you can then pass the results to `v-html`.